# Build fast-runtime for kusama on PolkadotSDK

Tags: kusama, testing, build, polkadot-sdk

Im quite a newbie in the new polkadot-sdk, can sm1 guide me how can I build a fast-runtime kusama polkadot image?
When I try to run a polkadot build with fast-runtime with kusama-local spec it tells:

```
1'   0: \x1B[91mInvalid input: `kusama-local` is not supported anymore as the kusama native runtime no longer part of the node.\x1B[0m\n' +
```

How to reproduce:

1. Checkout latest&greatest polkadot-sdk repo
2. Create a dockerfile in :polkadot-sdk/docker/dockerfiles/polkadot/polkadot_builder.Dockerfile

```
# This is the build stage for Polkadot. Here we create the binary in a temporary image.
FROM docker.io/paritytech/ci-linux:production as builder

WORKDIR /polkadot
COPY . /polkadot

RUN cargo build --locked --release --features=fast-runtime

# This is the 2nd stage: a very small image where we copy the Polkadot binary."
FROM docker.io/parity/base-bin:latest

LABEL description="Multistage Docker image for Polkadot: a platform for web3" \
    io.parity.image.type="builder" \
    io.parity.image.authors="chevdor@gmail.com, devops-team@parity.io" \
    io.parity.image.vendor="Parity Technologies" \
    io.parity.image.description="Polkadot: a platform for web3" \
    io.parity.image.source="https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/${VCS_REF}/docker/dockerfiles/polkadot/polkadot_builder.Dockerfile" \
    io.parity.image.documentation="https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/"

COPY --from=builder /polkadot/target/release/polkadot /usr/local/bin

RUN /usr/local/bin/polkadot --version


EXPOSE 30333 9933 9944 9615
VOLUME ["/data"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/polkadot"]
```

1. Build it,

```
docker build . -f=./docker/dockerfiles/polkadot/polkadot_builder.Dockerfile
```

3. Reference such image in a parachain-launch config file:

```
relaychain:
  image: <newDockerImage>
  chain: kusama-local
  runtimeGenesisConfig:
    configuration:
      config:
        validation_upgrade_cooldown: 10
        validation_upgrade_delay: 10
  env:
    RUST_LOG: parachain::candidate-backing=trace,parachain::candidate-selection=trace,parachain::pvf=trace,parachain::collator-protocol=trace,parachain::provisioner=trace
  flags:
    - --rpc-methods=unsafe
    - --wasm-execution=compiled
    - --execution=wasm
  nodes:
    - name: alice
    - name: bob

parachains:
- image: mangatasolutions/mangata-node:develop-fast
  chain:
    base: mangata-kusama-local
    collators:
      - alice
      - bob
    sudo: alice
    skipCollatorSelection: true
    skipBalances: true
  id: 2110
  parachain: true
  flags:
    - --rpc-methods=unsafe
    - --force-authoring
    - --wasm-execution=compiled
    - --execution=wasm
  relaychainFlags:
    - --wasm-execution=compiled
    - --execution=wasm
  env:
    # RUST_LOG: info,block_builder=trace,block_shuffler=trace,runtime::ver=trace,txpool=trace,rpc::nonce=trace
    RUST_LOG: info,block_builder=trace
  volumePath: /mangata/data
  nodes:
  - flags:
    - --alice
  - flags:
    - --bob
```

Answer (score 0):

Kusama and Polkadot are not available if you're using versions later than v1.3.0.

For testing with the polkadot-sdk, consider using Rococo or Westend instead.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1731

Comment: hii, Thanks for the answer!

Ok... so now there is no literally way to test Kusama specific related chain-specs from 1.3.0 onward? I used to setup a relay with Kusama vertical and then do the final validations. Mainly because we have some changes that depends on the chain.
Thanks!

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes.